# JSTree cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jstree

This is my json structure that i output to the console:

```
0:
    ApplicationName: null
    ApplicationsId: "024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c"
    CreatedOn: "2019-04-03T23:20:30.063584"
    Path: ""
    children: [{…}]
    id: "a97620e2-690c-4c5d-9a53-4c4ef713156e"
    parent: "#"
    text: "main 1"
    __proto__: Object
1:
    ApplicationName: null
    ApplicationsId: "024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c"
    CreatedOn: "2019-04-03T23:20:36.0979761"
    Path: ""
    children: []
    id: "993f86eb-df13-40ea-a519-263bb844ee43"
    parent: "#"
    text: "main 2"
    __proto__: Object
2:
    ApplicationName: null
    ApplicationsId: "024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c"
    CreatedOn: "2019-04-03T23:20:36.1190942"
    Path: ""
    children: [{…}]
    id: "fe0aeaad-468d-4482-856a-b87273df4b80"
    parent: "#"
    text: "main 3"
    __proto__: Object
3:
    ApplicationName: null
    ApplicationsId: "024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c"
    CreatedOn: "2019-04-03T23:20:36.1238693"
    Path: ""
    children: [{…}]
    id: "279931ad-e89c-4056-b0bc-7be41339baba"
    parent: "#"
    text: "main 4"
    __proto__: Object
```

I'm trying to load it into jstree but I keep getting the error:

> cannot read property 'id' of undefined at parse_flat

This is how I declare my jstree at the moment:

```
 $("#tree").jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                "url": "@Url.Action("DisplayChildren", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                "dataType":"json"
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the controller that gets called:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Repositories/Repositories/DisplayChildren")]
public JsonResult DisplayChildren()
{
    var output = repositoriesData.GetChildren("");
    return Json(output);
}
```

Am I missing something? I already changed the names of some objects and the children objects all have an existing parentid.

EDIT:

I added a JSON.stringify to see if I can convert the output. The error is gone but nothing shows up on screen. The console shows this though:

```
[{"id":"a97620e2-690c-4c5d-9a53-4c4ef713156e","parent":"#","text":"main 1","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:30.063584","children":[{"id":"f3e0a4aa-f466-455d-b102-c79e62775e63","parent":"a97620e2-690c-4c5d-9a53-4c4ef713156e","text":"main 1 - sub 1","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:36.1176032","children":[]}]},{"id":"993f86eb-df13-40ea-a519-263bb844ee43","parent":"#","text":"main 2","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:36.0979761","children":[]},{"id":"fe0aeaad-468d-4482-856a-b87273df4b80","parent":"#","text":"main 3","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:36.1190942","children":[{"id":"aa230395-0731-48ff-824d-304237c34034","parent":"fe0aeaad-468d-4482-856a-b87273df4b80","text":"main 3 - sub 1","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:36.1206852","children":[{"id":"0b16f5f2-032a-43d6-8b24-ac4368d86c5e","parent":"aa230395-0731-48ff-824d-304237c34034","text":"main 3 - sub 1 - subsub 1","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:36.1223118","children":[]}]}]},{"id":"279931ad-e89c-4056-b0bc-7be41339baba","parent":"#","text":"main 4","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:36.1238693","children":[{"id":"95a31a4b-6bf1-47b3-91e0-2ffddd4deec1","parent":"279931ad-e89c-4056-b0bc-7be41339baba","text":"main 4 - sub 1","ApplicationName":null,"ApplicationsId":"024e5e4b-9afd-44af-be33-8cab3eb6ce8c","Path":"","CreatedOn":"2019-04-03T23:20:36.1255852","children":[]}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your ajax call, or else you wouldn't be getting that error which is twofold. Also, you're not declaring jstree, you're creating an object with the id of tree and using a jstree function to create JSON to capture the result.

1) You have a string instead of a flat (parse_flat) as your id type (cannot read property 'id').
2) Your ApplicationName is null (of undefined).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what a flat is? the sample data from the site uses a string as well for the id?

Comment: I've never heard of a flat before either but they sound cool. They can look like strings since they are record identifiers. Check your database to make sure you set the data type correctly.

Comment: Actually, it's most definitely that. Look at your url parameter:

Comment: you are changing all of your values to a string.

Comment: Yeah because I want it as a string. I don't think theres a datatype called flat